# Mapping int to int (in Java)

Tags: java, algorithm, dictionary, integer, mapping

In Java.

How can I map a set of numbers(integers for example) to another set of numbers?
All the numbers are positive and all the numbers are unique in their own set.

The first set of numbers can have any value, the second set of numbers represent indexes of an array, and so the goal is to be able to access the numbers in the second set through the numbers in the first set. This is a one to one association.

Speed is crucial as the method will have to be called many times each second.

Edit: I tried it with SE hashmap implementation, but found it to be slow for my purposes.

Comment: Can you give an example, please?

Comment: HashMap<Integer, Integer>

Comment: I think HashMap would be too slow. But yes, in essence it is basically a map between integers.

Comment: How would it be slow? It's constant time lookup. What's faster than constant time?

Comment: Well an array's access if faster than a hashmap's, and well i need to squeeze as much speed out of it as I can.

Comment: What operation is too slow for you?

Comment: @BrandonLing constant time primitive array access. Keeping two arrays might be an option if speed is really that crucial. Still, all this depends on OP's needs. OP, please provide more details on how the data is currently stored and what exactly do you need to do with it.

Comment: How many numbers you have?

Comment: @Bendegúz Nagy It's probably negligible, but even if you did use array with index then an element with value 1 million would me you need  to allocate a minimum 1 million size array

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's an article, devoted to this problem (with a solution): [Implementing a world fastest Java int-to-int hash map](http://java-performance.info/implementing-world-fastest-java-int-to-int-hash-map/)

Code can be found in related [GitHub repository](https://github.com/mikvor/hashmapTest).  (Best results are in class IntIntMap4a.java )

Citation from the article:

---

**Summary**

If you want to optimize your hash map for speed, you have to do as much as you can of the following list:

- Use underlying array(s) with capacity equal to a power of 2 - it will allow you to use cheap & instead of expensive % for array index
- Do not store the state in the separate array - use dedicated fields for free/removed keys and values.
- Interleave keys and values in the one array - it will allow you to load a value into memory for free.
- Implement a strategy to get rid of 'removed' cells - you can sacrifice some of remove performance in favor of more frequent get/put.
- Scramble the keys while calculating the initial cell index - this is required to deal with the case of consecutive keys.

  <sub>Yes, I know how to use citation formatting. But it looks awful and doesn't handle bullet lists well.</sub>

Comment: "Too many pending edits" so leaving as a comment instead. The article link is broken so use an archive to see what used to be there: https://web.archive.org/web/20180226192440/http://java-performance.info/implementing-world-fastest-java-int-to-int-hash-map/

Answer (score 2):

The structure you are looking for is called an associative array. In computer science, an associative array, map, symbol table, or dictionary is an abstract data type composed of a collection of (key, value) pairs, such that each possible key appears just once in the collection.

In java in particular as already mentioned this is easily done with a HashMap.

```
HashMap<Integer, Integer> cache = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
```

You can insert elements with the method `put`

```
cache.put(21, 42);
```

and you can retrieve a value with `get`

```
Integer key = 21
Integer value = cache.get(key);
System.out.println("Key: " + key +" value: "+ value); 

Key: 21 value: 42
```

If you want to iterate through data you need to define an iterator:

```
Iterator<Integer> Iterator = cache.keySet().iterator();

while(Iterator.hasNext()){
  Integer key = Iterator.next();
  System.out.println("key: " + key + " value: " + cache.get(key));
}
```

Comment: The best answer of all here about associative arrays in general and HashMap in particular.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like `HashMap<Integer,Integer>` is what you're looking for.

Comment: @WinterBreeze You're going to have to be more specific than that. You should include these details in your original post.

Comment: @WinterBreeze HashMaps have O(1) access time. You're not gonna get much faster than that.

Comment: @Rubixus Yes you are. The constants are not good enough for his case, it actually happens quite often, due to the boxing overhead and too much method invokations. Constants do matter.

Comment: @Rubixus I belive that HashMap's access time is O(log n), also the autoboxing overhead can be crippling, and HashMap is not catche friendly, I'd be better off just iterating over an array linearly, if there are not too many records in it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to use an external library, you can use apache's [IntToIntMap](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/facet/org/apache/lucene/util/collections/IntToIntMap.html), which is a part of [Apache Lucene](https://lucene.apache.org/).

It implements a pretty efficient int to int map that uses primitives for tasks that should not suffer the boxing overhead.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a limit for the size of the first list, you can just use a large array.  Suppose you know there first list only has numbers 0-99, you can use int[100].  Use the first number as an array index.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements can be satisfied by the `Map` interface.  As an example, see `HashMap<K,V>`.

See [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) and [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)